# Circumvent forced online contacts / sync?

Tags: 8.1, contacts

I was thinking of buying a Nokia Lumia 630, which currently is rather cheap here. Windows phone 8.1 is on it.
I have read that you are forced to store the contacts online, sync'ed with an MS account with win phone 8.1. I.e. you cannot store contacts on SIM or the phone and use them offline.
I basically want to use the device as "phone which has a camera and other goodies", but not for internet access. For the time being, I do not intend to get a contract for mobile internet access at all.

So, is there a *reliable* way to get around that restriction which lasts longer than to the next windows update?
(I've read some comments that one could use localhost as outlook server, but the commenter doubted the longevity of that hack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option is not available, even though there is a built in option to import contacts from SIM card, once you start that wizard, it will ask you to choose a cloud account to save them to.

The workaround us simple, connect it to WiFi and download your contacts, leave it like that. The contacts will be available just not synced. If you wish you can connect it from time to time to a WiFi spot just to sync. I actually have a 630 with no connection and that's what I am doing.

Comment: Okay, I'll just try it that way and see how I like it